# Is the sqlsrv_query function enough to prevent DB injection?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to prevent DB injection on my first web api and i'm not sure if using the sqlsrv_query function is enough.

Comment: No function can guarantee that. SQL injection happens when you compose code from untrusted sources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you [should be](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-query.php) [safe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296184(v=sql.105).aspx), provided that you:

- parameterize all user supplied values with `?` placeholders
- provide values for each placeholder in `$params` in the correct order

Note however that this applies for values only - you cannot parameterize column names or table names in this way. In which case, you will need to perform validation such as whitelisting of permissible columns / tables etc.